# MySQL Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

Really, what could possibly be wrong?!  It does not get any more simple - the entire query:

```
line 1: use foo
line 2: 
line 3: select * from test_table_1;
```

**Error Code:**

> 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
>         to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from test_table_1' at
>         line 3    0.002 sec

*The line numbers are for reference only - there not actually in the query window.*

I'm trying to run this extremely simple query in `MySQLWorkbench` and it's throwing a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a semicolon:

```
use foo;
```

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you explained **why** a semicolon is needed, instead of just "Try adding". "Try adding" is a suggestion, not an answer. :)

Comment: Gracias! that's the missing link.  I keep forgetting that MySQL is very particular about the semicolon.  My bad habits :^)

Answer (score 0):

Without semicolon both statements will treat as single one.
By adding semicolon MySQL will treat both statements as multiple queries.
Try using

```
 use foo;
    /*and then*/
    select * from foo;
```